# Wie kann man "just in case" übersetzen?

Tags: translation

Gibt es in der Umgangssprache eine andere Übersetzung für "just in case"? Im Wörterbuch kann ich nur einige wie "für alle Fälle", "im Notfall", aber die klingen mir zu schriftsprachlich.

Könnte man auch ein paar Beispiele geben für "just in case" mit Ergänzung (a) und unabhängig benutzt (b)?

> a) We keep a lot of food on hand, just in case there's a storm.
>
> b) Make sure you have extra batteries available, just in case.

Comment: Eine etwas freiere Übersetzung für (a): "Wir haben genug Essen verstaut, falls einmal ein Sturm kommen sollte." Diese ist allerdings umgangssprachlicher als Ingmars Übersetzung und hat auch einen leicht anderen Sinn als das Original.

Answer (score 22):

"Für alle Fälle" und "für den Notfall" sind keine schlechten Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten. Etwas salopper wäre noch "nur für den Fall" (das ist dann auch recht nah am Original):

> Wir haben ausreichend Essen eingelagert, für den Fall dass ein Unwetter kommt.
>
> Du solltest ausreichend Batterien in Reserve haben, nur für den Fall.

Comment: Vielleicht noch dazu als eine Möglichkeit: "nur um sicher zu gehen"

Comment: Auch: "für den Fall der Fälle"

Comment: ähnlich @Milchgesicht: _um auf Nummer Sicher zu gehen_ (vielleicht _sicher_ klein)

Comment: Oder: "sicher ist sicher".

Comment: Was heißt hier keine schlechten Übersetzungen, "für alle Fälle" und "nur für den Fall" sind hier *die* Übersetzungen.

Comment: Ich sprach von _Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten_; die eine richtige und einzig wahre Übersetzung gibt es nämlich nicht, es sind immere mehrere Möglichkeiten.

Comment: Schon klar, damit wollte ich nur ausdrücken, dass das meine Plätze 1 und 2 sind.

Answer (score 4):

For a more colloquial variety, consider:

> Wir haben eine ganze Menge Essen da, nur falls es gewittert/nur falls ein Unwetter kommt.

Keep in mind, that is totally colloquial to the extent of being quite ungrammatical.

Your second example, where "just in case" is detached from further elaboration of a particular case, the perfect translation, whether colloquial or formal is

> Denk dran, Reservebatterien zu haben, **für alle Fälle**.

Answer (score 3):

Another colloquial possibility is sicherheitshalber.

> I made a backup, just in case the server dies.

in German

> Ich hab sicherheitshalber ein Backup gemacht, falls der Server stirbt.

Answer (score 3):

"Nur für den Fall"

```
a) Wir haben immer einen Vorrat an Lebensmitteln, nur für den Fall, dass ein Sturm aufkommt.
b) Sieh zu/Stelle sicher, dass du immer Batterien übrig hast. Nur für den Fall.
```

Grammatikalisch wahrscheinlich nicht ganz korrekt, aber fühlt sich gesprochen weniger falsch an, als meine freien Übersetzungen der Beispielsätze ;D

Answer (score 2):

**falls**

is a pretty handy version of "Für den Fall".

http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/falls

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use

> …, nur zur Sicherheit